# get value from one slider and change other sliders based on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

sorry i am just beginner here, i would like like to get the value of the slider and dynamically change the other sliders based on that value
for example : if the first slider value is: first_slider x 
then my second slider will be : second_slider = x + 20 
and third slider will be : third_slider = x + 10

here are the code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/fe7j3ohv/)

HTML

```
<h2>roundSlider</h2> 
<p>For more details check the website: <a href="http://roundsliderui.com/">http://roundsliderui.com/</a></p>

<div id="first_slider"></div>
<div id="second_slider"></div>`
```

JS

```
$("#first_slider").roundSlider({
    handleShape: "dot",
    width: 22,
    radius: 100,
    value: 15,
    circleShape: "half-top",
    sliderType: "min-range"
});

$("#second_slider").roundSlider({
    handleShape: "dot",
    width: 22,
    radius: 100,
    value: 15,
    circleShape: "half-top",
    sliderType: "min-range"
});
$("#third_slider").roundSlider({
    handleShape: "dot",
    width: 22,
    radius: 100,
    value: 15,
    circleShape: "half-top",
    sliderType: "min-range"
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Just do `value += 30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to review documentation of plugin for it.

I got you need to change values of other sliders when value of first slider changed. In documentation, you'll see the "change" event as a function. Then there's a method called "setValue" which deals with changing value of sliders. So, you need to create something like that on slider1.

```
$("#first_slider").roundSlider({
    handleShape: "dot",
    width: 22,
    radius: 100,
    value: 15,
    circleShape: "half-top",
    sliderType: "min-range",
    change: function(event) {
        var value = event.value;
        $('#second_slider').roundSlider('setValue', value + 20);
        $('#third_slider').roundSlider('setValue', value + 10);
    }
});
```

Here's the edited version of your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fe7j3ohv/28/

Answer (score 0):

If by value of the slider you mean a value of the text in the div then try this: first check first slider to see if you found your value, if so, over-write whatever is in the second slider with desired value.

```
var first_slider = $(div#first_slider).text();
var second_slider = $(div#second_slider);
var search_for_value = 2;
var desired_value = 'replace with anything you want to display in second slider';

if (first_slider===search_for_value){
   second_slider.html(desired_value);
}
```